# Scala call length() on very long string throws exception: Maximum String literal length exceeded

Tags: java, scala

I wrote a scala solution for [HackerRank BigSorting](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/big-sorting/problem) , 
and got RuntimeException in some test case. I tested the input in [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/PmnOAiZuSGOINdwe1Y7nlg), it seems the problem is caused by calling length() on a very long string, but the same [java solution](https://www.hackerrank.com/rest/contests/master/challenges/big-sorting/hackers/wang7x/download_solution) has no problem, is this a bug?
my solution code is :

```
object Solution {
    def stringSort(x:String, y:String):Boolean = {
        var result = true

        if(x.length < y.length){
            result = true
        }else if(x.length > y.length){
            result = false
        }else{
            var founded = false
            var i = 0
            while(i < x.length && !founded){
                var xi = x.charAt(i)
                var yi = y.charAt(i)
                if(xi != yi){
                    result = xi < yi
                    founded = true
                }
                i += 1
            }
        }
        result
    }

    def bigSort(unsorted:Array[String]):Array[String] = {
        return unsorted.sortWith(stringSort)
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val sc = new java.util.Scanner (System.in);
        var n = sc.nextInt();
        var unsorted = new Array[String](n);
        for(unsorted_i <- 0 to n-1) {
           unsorted(unsorted_i) = sc.next();
        }
        print(bigSort(unsorted).mkString("\n"))
        // your code goes here
    }
}
```

the exception is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Maximum String literal length exceeded
    at scala.tools.asm.ByteVector.putUTF8(ByteVector.java:213)
    at scala.tools.asm.ClassWriter.newUTF8(ClassWriter.java:1114)
    at scala.tools.asm.ClassWriter.newString(ClassWriter.java:1582)
    at scala.tools.asm.ClassWriter.newConstItem(ClassWriter.java:1064)
    at scala.tools.asm.MethodWriter.visitLdcInsn(MethodWriter.java:1187)
    at scala.tools.asm.tree.LdcInsnNode.accept(LdcInsnNode.java:71)
    at scala.tools.asm.tree.InsnList.accept(InsnList.java:162)
    at scala.tools.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(MethodNode.java:820)
    at scala.tools.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(MethodNode.java:730)
    at scala.tools.asm.tree.ClassNode.accept(ClassNode.java:412)
...
```

java solution

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        String[] unsorted = new String[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) unsorted[i] = in.next();

        Arrays.sort(unsorted,new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String a, String b) 
            {
                return StringAsIntegerCompare(a,b);
            }
        });

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("");
        for(String num : unsorted)
            output.append(num+"\n");
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    static int StringAsIntegerCompare(String s1, String s2)
    {
        if(s1.length() > s2.length()) return 1;
        if(s1.length() < s2.length()) return -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
        {
            if((int)s1.charAt(i) > (int)s2.charAt(i)) return 1;
            if((int)s1.charAt(i) < (int)s2.charAt(i)) return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post exception?

Comment: add exception in the post, and you can check complete output in https://scastie.scala-lang.org/PmnOAiZuSGOINdwe1Y7nlg

Comment: I searched the exception, found https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/7527, it looks like a scala bug

Comment: Looks like they tried to solve that and put check in compiler. Now you get error during compilation instead of corrupted class file. But I don't see any long string literal in your code.

Comment: In Scastie, you can remove `length` call and get the same exception. The issue is the long string literal itself. Since your solution code doesn't have such long string literals, that's not the problem with your solution. You need to post the exception you get from HackerRank originally.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov yes, you are right, I made a mistake, the string which in Scastie was copied from HackerRank Test Case #3,  HackerRank does not print the exception and limit customer test case to 50k data, so I have to tested it in Scastie

Comment: @talex the long string came from the input of HackerRank Test Case #3, not in my code. as Alexey said, maybe it's not caused by `length()`, I will test the scala solution locally to know which RuntimeException it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only substantial difference between Java and Scala code that I can see is that Scala `sortWith` creates a new array, unlike `Arrays.sort` (and probably has some intermediate overhead too), so you could be running out of memory. You can instead try

```
import scala.math.Ordering
import scala.util.Sorting

val byLength: Ordering[String] = ... // your implementation, similar to Java comparator

Sorting.quickSort(unordered)(byLength) // instead of sortWith, sorts in-place
```

See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/math/Ordering.html and http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/util/Sorting$.html for relevant documentation.

Comment: Thank you! I tested the new solution, the problem is solved, this is not a scala bug,  I lack the knowledge of Sorting

Answer (score 2):

It is curious that a java solution, asking each string for its length, works while the Scala solution does not.

For what it's worth, the challenge is solvable without invoking the `length` method on any `String` element. I came up with an accepted solution (21 lines of code) using `isDefinedAt()` to determine the relative lengths of the `String` elements.

---

As requested, here is the solution I came up with.

For those not familiar with HackerRank challenges, the very poor Scala code in the `main()` method is supplied code (i.e. *not my fault!*). I wrote the `sortum()` code.

```
def sortum(arr:Array[String],start:Int = 0, end:Int = 1000000):Array[String] =
  if (arr.length < 2) arr             //only one of this length, return it
  else if (end-start < 1) arr.sorted  //multiple of the same length, sort them
  else {                              //partition into two groups
    val mid = (end-start)/2 + start
    val (a,b) = arr.partition(_.isDefinedAt(mid))
    if      (a.isEmpty) sortum(b,start,mid)
    else if (b.isEmpty) sortum(a,mid+1,end)
    else sortum(b,start,mid) ++ sortum(a,mid+1,end)
  }

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val sc = new java.util.Scanner (System.in);
  var n = sc.nextInt();
  var unsorted = new Array[String](n);
  for(unsorted_i <- 0 to n-1) {
    unsorted(unsorted_i) = sc.next();
  }
  sortum(unsorted).foreach(println)
}
```

It's your basic binary search pattern used to segregate stings by their lengths.

---

Of course, now that we know that string `.length` isn't the source of the problem, a much simpler solution is available.

```
unsorted.map(_.length)  
        .zipWithIndex  
        .sortWith{case ((al,ax),(bl,bx)) =>
          al < bl || (al == bl && unsorted(ax) < unsorted(bx))
        }.foreach(x => println(unsorted(x._2)))
```

Comment: I posted java solution, could you share your solution, I'm curious how you did it. I have seen a lot solutions, none of them mentioned `isDefinedAt()`